# HTTPS sites won't work on Chrome, others don't work at all on Yosemite

Tags: imac, google-chrome, internet, macos

All HTTPS websites (such as Google) are showing this message

```
This webpage is not available, `Error code: ERR_TIMED_OUT`
```

I'm using `Chrome 38.0.2125.104` on a mid-2011 iMac with OS X Yosemite. No other browser works at all, such as Safari, Firefox etc, but all sites work on other computers.

Using a socks proxy works, but that is not ideal, and I don't want to be stuck using Bing or restoring to Mavericks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same issue, it looks like a bug.  It impacts both Chrome and Safari.

I found if I change the account profile settings to allow it to administer, it will start working again.

Not a great long-term solution, but hopefully Apple will patch it soon.