# Chrome 79: https sites don't load while http works fine

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Just upgraded to Chrome 79 from 78 via its internal updater. Now only http sites load, not https.

- I am on Yosemite
- Chrome v 79

Chrome says "This site can’t be reached" and "ERR_FAILED". Including for 
some of Chrome's own help pages.

Like the one used when trying to report this: 
"https://support.google.com/chrome/go/feedback_confirmation"

And the one that is used to get per-page security report: "https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=ui_security_indicator"

My research shows:

"[HTTPS sites won't work on Chrome, others don't work at all on Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151392/https-sites-wont-work-on-chrome-others-dont-work-at-all-on-yosemite)"

cross-browser problems with https but Safari still works for me.

It says something about "change the account profile settings to allow it to administer". I don't know what that means.

How can I apply that information or just fix https on chrome 79?

Comment: "...change the account profile settings to allow it to administer" in the linked askdifferent q&a probably means: upgrade the user from standard to admin in SysPrefs > Users & Groups. But the q&a is unrelated to the current issue of v79.

Comment: Stay with v78 (like me on ElCap) until Google fixed it.

Comment: @klanomath Too late :). Well I have Safari, and a second computer with Chrome, so I'll hold it back there. I usually wait a few weeks for kinks like this to be straightened out, but this time I was seduced by the Tab Freeze feature.

Comment: Finally found *something* on this issue: "https://piunikaweb.com/2019/12/13/google-chrome-mac-https-sites-err_failed-notice/"

Comment: I have the same problem since ~10 days (first with Chromiuim/later with Chrome). Link at Google Chrome support: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/18507302?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug, which apparently affected 10.10 (Yosemite) and 10.11 (El Capitan) only, has been fixed in Google Chrome 79.0.3945.88.

The [changelog](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/79.0.3945.79..79.0.3945.88?pretty=fuller&n=10000) doesn't mention it though.

So download the [latest](https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/chrome/) installer, install it, remove any method to block Google updates¹ and be happy again with a working Google Chrome browser.

---

¹: I disabled access of ksfetch/Google Updater to gvt1.com and google.com with a packet filter

Comment: Yes, I notices; and updated. All good now...